# regex find -> found and replace

Tags: php, regex

I have this code!

```
<div class="time\54>  
<div class="time\98">  
<div class="time\69">  
<div id="result">{INFO}</div>
```

I need to take last

```
'<div class="time\69">'
```

Then take numbers in this last div after 'time',and sum  it (6+9), then put result into {INFO} field.
**Need use only preg_replace**

Result:

```
<div class="time\54>  
<div class="time\98">  
<div class="time\69">  
<div id="result">15</div>
```

How to take last child (element div)?
How to do a  sum  of numbers?
How to remember (use $1 , or %1) ? 
Thx.

Comment: Question is : how do you have that html? Do you generate it via PHP? via a `foreach`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$src = '<div class="edit\5451" style="width:100%; text-align:left">  
<div style="padding:0px 25px 0px 25px" align="left" class="edit\9874">  
<div class="edit\6924" style="padding:0px 0px 6px 0px">  
<div id="result">{RESULT}</div> ';

echo preg_replace('#(<div class="edit[\\\])([0-9]+)("[^<]+<div id="result">)([^<]+)(</div>)#mse','"$1$2$3".array_sum(str_split($2))."$5"', $src);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you **have** to use preg_replace, the following would work:

```
$str = '<div class="time\54>
<div class="time\98">
<div class="time\12">  
<div class="time\69">
<div id="result">{INFO}</div>';

function replace_callback($matches) {
        return $matches[1] . array_sum(str_split($matches[2],"1"));
}

$result = preg_replace_callback('#((?:.*<div class="time\\\\\d+">)*.*<div class="time\\\\(\d+)">.*)\{INFO\}#s', 'replace_callback', $str);
```

If you can't even use preg_replace_callback, this is an alternative with only preg_replace:

```
$result = preg_replace('#((?:.*<div class="time\\\\\d+">)*.*<div class="time\\\\(\d+)">.*)\{INFO\}#se', '\'\1\' . array_sum(str_split(\'\2\',\'1\'))', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to take last child (element div)?

Regexp is not a proper tool for dealing with HTML. Use [`DOMDocument::loadHTML()`](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) to create a DOM tree, then accessing last `<div class="time\...">` should be easy.

> How to do a sum of numbers?

```
$number = '69';
$digits = str_split($number); // Array (0 => 6, 1 => 9)
$sum    = array_sum($digits);   // 15
```

Comment: Need to use only one function preg_replace()

Comment: explode() does not allows empty delimiters ;)

Comment: str_split() is better for this.